# input type="submit" instead of input type="button" with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webforms

I have an AJAX form I'm setting up, using an `<input type="button">` with a jQuery .click action being set.

The problem is, because there is no `<input type="submit"`> in the form, the form doesn't submit in a traditional way, so form validators don't always work, and pressing the enter button does nothing.

If I DO add a submit input, when it's clicked (or enter is hit, etc.), the page reloads as if it is not an AJAX form.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a submit button. The submit button will be more compatible in terms of default browser behavior, such as pressing enter. Then, on the submit event, just cancel the form submission and run your AJAX code.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
<!--Blah Blah Blah-->
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you're using jQuery, you can use a more "clean" method

```
$('#form_id').bind('submit',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Will prevent the submit...
  //Add additional code here
});
```

Comment: if he attaches to form's submit event using jQuery, there's no need for `onsubmit="return false;"` outdated functionality. `e.preventDefault()` does the trick already.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: I know that. I was offering two methods to achieve what he was doing.

Answer (score 4):

Rather change form's `submit` behaviour and keep your `<input type="submit">` button as well:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do ajax submition
    $.ajax({
        url: "SomeURL",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            // do the success stuff
        },
        error: function(xhr, status err) {
            // do the error stuff
        }
    });
});
```

**Advantage**: The good thing is this will work in all cases when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on any of the form's input elements or click the submit button. It will always work without exception.